# Installing a plugin for quodlibet as a patch

Tags: python, patch

I'm trying to update a plugin for quodlibet. I fetched a `.patch` file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/issues/attachmentText?id=588&aid=-1157097690432225774&name=new-notify-plugin.patch&token=-pMAbjZChL62wv3Q5naESbu4AQs%3A1362510059413).

I navigate into the directory where the plugin is placed

```
/usr/share/pyshared/quodlibet/plugins/events
```

and copy in the `.patch` file. Then I run the command

```
sudo patch -b notify.py new-notify-plugin.patch
```

which gives me

```
patching file notify.py Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file notify.py.rej
```

The `.rej` file contains the whole content of the `.patch` file, just the first three lines changed to

```
--- notify.py
+++ notify.py
```

What I am doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the same version of notify.py that the patch was written for, and the differences between the file you have and the file the patch expected are too great for `patch` to figure out how to apply the patch to your version.

Comment: could it work if I try to override some special parts in notify.py manually?

Comment: @32bitfloat, frankly, if you have to ask the question, the odds of you successfully manually applying the patch are pretty low.  I see the patch [was already merged](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/source/detail?r=0fc12e8acb53); it'd probably be easier to upgrade to a version that already has that feature.